# Restricting SQL query in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a query, say for example `select username as test , userpassword as testing, concat(userpassword,username), concat(userpassword,username) as test1 from mytable`

The result of the above query will be the appropriate column details. This query is given as input by user in our web application, where we are restricting the display of certain columns like `userpassword` by showing `*******`.

But in the above query, due to the use of alias name for our columns and the concat function, our passwords are being displayed.

I want a code which displays `*******` in place of the aliased column name, i.e. even after the name is changed it should be displayed only as `*******`.

Is there any way to restrict the `as` query and `concat` query only for the columns which we want to display as `*******`.

Comment: Restricting schema level access from JAVA is not good idea. You should do it on DB level only. Assuming user input will not be DMLs, Create a separate db user to execute queries from User input and restrict access for that user. You may want to create public views which are accessible for querying user input and not the schema. Don't include such columns in public views which you want to hide from user input queries.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: sorry. I am using mssql.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, don't let the user run his own SQLs at all. Also, do not store passwords in plain text in the DB. If you really can't do anything about it the preferred solution somewhat depends on what levels of security are available with your DBMS. But in any case a user should be added to the DB whose access is restricted to the data and the operations that you want to allow to your users - and used by your application when establishing the connection. Look up privileges and/or grants in the manual of your DBMS. If you're lucky it supports column level security so that you can disable access to the password column. The DBMS will take care of any aliasing then.